# Showing that the limit of an infinite product equals a sine function times a t term

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

I need help with a textbook exercise (Gamelin's Complex Analysis, Ch.8 Section 3 Problem 14). This exercise requires me to show that  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \prod_{-m\leq k \leq tm} \left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right) =\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z} t^z.$$

Since we know that $$\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z}= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$$
I have tried factoring this expression and massaging it into the above form. However, I don't know how to include the t factor into the equation. Also the term isn't symmetric so the negative product doesn't easily come forth. How would one go about solving this? Is the Gamma function required?

Answer (score 0):

For a solution, it's sufficient to use $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{an<k<bn}\frac1k=\log\frac ba$ for $0<a<b$, which may be shown in different ways (Riemann sums, or the fact that $\sum\limits_{0<k<n}\frac1k-\log n$ has a finite limit as $n\to\infty$, etc.).

Assume first that $t>1$, then we need to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{n<k<tn}(1+z/k)=t^z$.

But, indeed, since $\log(1+z/k)=z/k+O(1/k^2)$ as $k\to\infty$, we get $$\sum_{n<k<tn}\log\left(1+\frac zk\right)=z\sum_{n<k<tn}\frac1k+O(n)\cdot O(1/n^2)$$ as $n\to\infty$, and the limit equals $z\log t$, as expected.

For $0<t<1$ we prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{tn<k<n}(1+z/k)=t^{-z}$, the same way.